# Get page count from an html like in chrome print preview with c#

Tags: c#, html, pdf, count

I have 1000+ HTML document for per month. 
And HTML file count is increasing per month.

Before me, every month my work-friend was opening these HTML files with chrome and opening print preview dialog in chrome and getting file page count and closing chrome tab for per HTML file.

I wrote an app in c# that is converting these HTML files to PDF and getting file count from PDF files. Some PDF files are smaller than 1 MB. But some PDF files are bigger than 30 MB and this bigger PDF files take time more than half hour for converting.
Is there easier way to calculate page count of HTML file than converting to PDF?
or 
Is there faster way to convert HTML file to PDF ?

Comment: How you are converting HTML to PDF, through any component? If it is a component then there may/may not be an option to count! If it is your own logic to convert, then may be based on what represent a page in your HTML (for ex: <p> tag or a tag with specific css class etc.) you can query, right?

Comment: I used EvoPdf library, i think i cant see anything about getting page count
http://www.evopdf.com/html-to-pdf-converter.aspx

Comment: Did you check this [Sample Code](http://www.evopdf.com/demo/HTML_to_PDF/PDF_Actions/Go_To_Page_Open_Action.aspx) section where I can see a line : `pdfDocument.Pages.Count` ?

Comment: This is after converting process. There is many function for after converting.